# The difference between life and scope for local variables?

Tags: java

I am studying java, where they often used scope and life of variable. What is the difference between life and scope for local variables?

Comment: [Here is a good article](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/scope-and-lifetime-of-variables) about that topic.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a "life of a variable". A variable has `scope`, and after going out of scope it's not accessible anymore. If that variable was referring to an object, the object becomes eligible for garbage collection. You might talk about an object's lifetime, but not a variable's.

In some comment the stack frame was mentioned, and how a local **variable** (i.e. the space taken by a variable on stack) would "be alive" in the stack frame for the duration of the method. However that's part of a different and more low level discussion, not related to variable scope. Nobody would discuss the stack frame and talk about variables "being alive".

Comment: Life:  
A local variable is alioeas long as its Stack
frame is on the Stack. In other words,
until the method. completes.Scope : 
A local variable is in scope only within the
method in which the variable was declared.
When its own method calls another, the
variable is alive, but not in scope until its
method resumes. You can use a variable only
when it is in scope.

Comment: @RAJA you can easily create smaller scopes than the whole method (ifs, whiles, try/catches or even just a plain old `{ }` scope for fun), so that's just not true.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of a variable is the part of the code where the variable is visible and can be used.

Usually, we do not really talk about the lifetime of a variable, but about the lifetime of an object. A non-null reference variable refers to an object, and as an object is no longer referred to by a variable it is eligable to be destroyed by the garbage collector.

The Java Language Specification also talks about how long variables exist. This is different for each of the 6 different kinds of variables. For example, a local variable ceases to exist as soon as the code block in which it was defined has completed execution. On the other hand, an instance variable (a variable which is part of an object) ceases to exist as soon as the object of which it is a part (as opposed to the object it refers to) is destroyed by the garbage collector. For more information, see [Section 4.12.3 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12).

Answer (score 1):

Life of a variable is the duration of time a variable exist in memory.

Scope of a variable is the places your variable can be accessed.